# .Net winform button bug?

Tags: .net, winforms

There seems to be a bug with .Net winform's button. If you left click and hold it on a winform button, then right click (while holding down your left click), then release your right click, then drag your button to outside of the button, then release your left click, it seems that your button will be "stucked" - it won't back to depressed state. Is this just me with my faulty mouse? How can one solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I find that funny so i juste tried, it doesn't do it in my VS. 
So i think it only a visual studio graphic bug...
Try to make and call the button in the code and after try to move it with your mouse and see if the problem is still here.